# How to make ad login faster?

Tags: active-directory

I work at a medium sized organisation with high staff turnover and internal movement(1) and I've noticed a consistent problem for our new users that each time they visit a new PC - and they are required to do this a lot over the first two years of they career - the login process with their AD account takes a long time.

The login process is slow because it creates then updates a local profile.(2)

I understand this situation arose a number of years ago when roaming profiles where slow and would have had a detrimental effect on our network.

**What are our options for speeding the login process? Have roaming profiles improved in both the network load and speed of login?**

Its worth bearing in mind that while the users suffering the most are a minority (less than %10 of the workforce), they are key front line staff and are not only  vital to the organisation, but any impact we can make to improve their use of IT will improve the level of service we can provide.

(1) Normal in a hospital.
(2) it is also a common IT support strategy to delete unused local profiles on machines where dozens (maybe hundreds) of local profiles have been created.

Comment: Based on your description, the issue sounds relegated to roaming profiles and poor network bandwidth.  I don't know what your network topology looks like (switches and server types), so I can only guess at this point.  If you provide more info, I can give you a better answer.  As for your additional questions; those are in regards to company/hospital policy--check with your CIO or Director for directions how to manage those local profiles.

Answer (score 0):

(1)Normal in a hospital? **Not sure there**

(2) Deleting local profiles is common and in fact was recommended and encouraged in Citrix environments. So that aspect is normal or at least in regular use in IT for many years.

- I imagine there are security considerations there as local cache and working files would be left around with the profile for exploit.
- Some consideration is made for efficiency there too as profiles can get quite large

Roaming profiles can be quite a handful unless all of your workstations are exactly the same also they do have an impact on network and server load and space.

So you are faced with a decision:

1. Do I use some user time to generate a local profile and put in the maintenance required to clean up periodically (not a huge task using delprof)?
2. Do I use server space and network bandwidth to copy a profile down to the workstation?

More of a resource decision in my opinion and really hard to answer without ALOT of specifics. Your mileage may vary based on those specifics.